# VBA - Unsure where error is in my if statement (with multiple conditions)

Tags: excel, vba

I am unsure why I am always getting the Else Condition, not the other one. I am unsure if my syntax for a double if condition is wrong. If someone could just verify that/have an idea what is wrong that would be great.

Basically if the value in that cell is 4 digits and the 1st letter is a F, there is no need for the error message.

```
 RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To RowCount
        If Len(Cells(i, 4).Value) = 4 And Left(Cells(i, 4), 1) = "F" Then
        'Do nothing, no IA Code errors
            MsgBox "no errors"
        Else
            MsgBox "Error, please resubmit"
            
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: This looks correct. There may be a issue with unqualified objects there (`Cells`)

Comment: Just before the If you could `MsgBox Len(Cells(i, 4).Value) & " = 4 And " & Left(Cells(i, 4), 1) & " = F"` so you can see what is being compared.

Comment: Your `RowCount` is based on column C `Cells(Rows.Count, "C")` but your test is based on column D `Cells(i, 4)`. Do you have the right colum?

Comment: Change your error command to `MsgBox "Error in cell " & Range("D" & i).Address(False, False) & " for value " & Range("D" & i).Value` and make sure the address and value are what you expect. I think you need to qualify your worksheet or verify you are on the correct column as mentioned by @Absinthe. The syntax of your `IF X And Y Then` is fine

Comment: "if the value in that cell is 4 digits and the 1st letter is a F" - a digit is a number, and F is not a number, so it's difficult to tell exactly what you need here.  Do you mean F then 3 digits (ie 0-9), or F then 3 characters (A-Z, 0-9) ?  You can use `If Not Cells(i, 4).Value Like "F???" ` (F plus 3 characters) or `If Not Cells(i, 4).Value Like "F###"` (F plus 3 digits) to flag errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have only changed "C" to 4, in Line 2. It looks like you are referring to the wrong column to assign RowCount.

```
Sub Error_NoError()
 RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To RowCount
        If Len(Cells(i, 4).Value) = 4 And Left(Cells(i, 4), 1) = "F" Then
        'Do nothing, no IA Code errors
            MsgBox "no errors"
        Else
            MsgBox "Error, please resubmit"
            
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```